# How do I create a texture with internal format `RG8UI` in WebGL2?

Tags: webgl2

The code snippet below attempts to create a texture and then checks `gl.getError()`. When the internal format is set to `RG8` the creation succeeds. I want to set the internal format to `RG8UI`, but this results in the creation failing. In firefox a warning is also printed to the console: `Mismatched internalFormat and format/type: 0x8238 and 0x8227/0x1401` where `0x8238=RG8UI`, `0x8227=RG`, and `0x1401=UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

As far as I can tell, [MDN's documentation on texImage2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) indicates the pairing of internal format `RG8UI` with format `RG` is allowed though it is not "texture filterable" whatever that means. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
const GL = WebGL2RenderingContext;
const w = 8;
const h = 8;
let texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RG8UI, w, h, 0, GL.RG, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

if (gl.getError() != GL.NO_ERROR) {
    throw new Error("Failed");
}
console.log("passed");
```

Comment: `GL.RG8UI` is an integral internal format, hence the format has to be integral, too. Change `GL.RG` to `GL.RG_INTEGER`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yup, that was the issue! Put that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: "not filterable" means you must set `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `TEXTURE_MAX_FITLER` to `NEAREST`. `NEAREST` = not filtered. Any other setting is filtered.

Comment: @gman Thanks, that's useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *imageformat* is an integral format, then the *format* has to be integral, too. Either an `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated.
Note, there the allowed  combinations of *internalformat*, *format* and *type* are specified: [Valid combinations of format, type, and sized internalformat](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#page=124&zoom=100,168,206). A valid combination is `RG8UI`, `RG_INTEGER`, `UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Change the format argument from `GL.RG` to `GL.RG_INTEGER`:

<s>`gl.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RG8UI, w, h, 0, GL.RG, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);`</s>

```js
gl.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RG8UI, w, h, 0, GL.RG_INTEGER, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```